# How to publish a chatbot to Azure from QnA knowledge base

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am creating a chatbot for my company - I have used Microsoft QnA to create a knowledge base, however I was following instructions from

https://www.meziantou.net/2017/05/16/creating-a-chat-bot-from-a-faq-with-azure-q-a-maker

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Connect/2017/T107

These videos/articles show a "BotService" preview. I am using the new "BotApp Service" and cannot figure out where to link up my knowledge base to my bot.

I am a true beginner to this and was encouraged by the video tutorials made with the old "BotService" - however when I have tried to do this, I've run into a wall with it already.

All I want to do is link up my current knowledgebase made in QnA to my Azure platform in order to use the bot on my website.

Thanks,

T

Answer (score 0):

T, you should publish the QA Knowledge base/Q&A as a service, a step by step guide can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/guides/publishkb) , I'd also recommend checking the QnA Maker page if you haven't already, it can be found [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/qna-maker/)

[image]